# Incorrect date in ExtJS 3.4.0

Tags: date, extjs

I have a problem with Date in ExtJs 3.4.0
In case when i set date like "01 January 2020" ExtJs save this like "01 December 2019"

```
xtype:  'datefield',
id:     _BIRTHDATE,
format: 'd.m.Y',
width:  200,
allowBlank: false,
name:   'birthDate',
fieldLabel : 'Date of birth'
```

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you set it and how it is saved. Please show your code.

But let me elaborate on the most probable cause:

You are off by one month, which could be caused by the fact that JavaScript's `getMonth()` returns ZERO for January and ELEVEN for December, while ExtJS builtin methods always return ONE for January and TWELVE for December (like every other sane programming language - which is why some people say JS is not a programming language, but a pain in the ass).

So, for instance if you have a datefield with dateFormat `Y-m-d` and you do

```
var dt = new Date();
str = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + dt.getMonth() + "-" + dt.getDate();
datefield.setValue(str);
```

you will be off by one month. So you have to handle dates with caution: never convert them manually, always use `Ext.Date.parse` and `Ext.Date.format`.